# How to customize the auto generated Dokka html to include a header and a footer

Tags: android, kotlin, documentation-generation, kotlin-dokka

I'm looking for a way to customize the html generated by Dokka to include a custom header and a footer. I've previously used Doclava in order to override the template for the generated HTML and was wondering if there was a way to do this in Dokka. Looking through their code, I came across the appendHeader and appendFooter functions but wasn't sure on how I can override these methods. https://github.com/Kotlin/dokka/blob/de2f32d91fb6f564826ddd7644940452356e2080/core/src/main/kotlin/Formats/KotlinWebsiteHtmlFormatService.kt#L10

My last resort is to modify the generated html files with a script by inserting a header after the first body tag and inserting the footer before the closing tag but hopefully there's a more elegant solution.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Edit: Ended up creating a hacky bash script

```
head=`cat head.html`
header=`cat header.html`
footer=`cat footer.html`

find build/dokka -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i "s|</HEAD>|$head</HEAD>|g" {} \;
find .build/dokka -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i "s|<BODY>|<BODY>$header|g" {} \;
find build/dokka -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i "s|</BODY>|$footer</BODY>|g" {} \;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's currently impossible I'm afraid. At least it's not straightforward. You can override content generation in `StructuredFormatService` and then recompile dokka.

In dokka v0.11.0 we added support for plugins (and rewritten dokka from scratch) and this functionality is one of planned plugins

Comment: Thanks for letting me know. For now I've just gone ahead and created a hacky bash script for it to insert a custom header and footer. Hope this can help others.

```
head=`cat head.html`
header=`cat header.html`
footer=`cat footer.html`

find build/dokka -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i "s|</HEAD>|$head</HEAD>|g" {} \;
find .build/dokka -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i "s|<BODY>|<BODY>$header|g" {} \;
find build/dokka -name "*.html" -type f -exec sed -i "s|</BODY>|$footer</BODY>|g" {} \;
```